# Launching celery worker creates too many connexions to redis

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm using **celery** with **redis** as a broker in a **django** project.

The problem I have is that even with no task running, just launching the worker produces up to 10 new connexions to redis server.

```
celery -A proj worker -l INFO
```

If I check `CLIENT LIST` in redis-cli I see this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> CLIENT LIST

id=272 addr=127.0.0.1:48846 fd=16 name= age=63 idle=63 flags=N db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20520 events=r cmd=sadd user=default
id=270 addr=127.0.0.1:48842 fd=14 name= age=64 idle=64 flags=N db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20520 events=r cmd=publish user=default
id=4 addr=127.0.0.1:46946 fd=8 name= age=14901 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=26 qbuf-free=32742 argv-mem=10 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=61466 events=r cmd=client user=default
id=265 addr=127.0.0.1:48832 fd=9 name= age=64 idle=0 flags=b db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20536 events=r cmd=brpop user=default
id=266 addr=127.0.0.1:48834 fd=10 name= age=64 idle=63 flags=N db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20520 events=r cmd=sadd user=default
id=273 addr=127.0.0.1:48848 fd=17 name= age=63 idle=2 flags=P db=2 sub=0 psub=1 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20504 events=r cmd=psubscribe user=default
id=274 addr=127.0.0.1:48850 fd=18 name= age=63 idle=63 flags=N db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20520 events=r cmd=sadd user=default
id=267 addr=127.0.0.1:48836 fd=11 name= age=64 idle=64 flags=N db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20496 events=r cmd=ping user=default
id=268 addr=127.0.0.1:48838 fd=12 name= age=64 idle=2 flags=N db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20520 events=r cmd=publish user=default
id=269 addr=127.0.0.1:48840 fd=13 name= age=64 idle=64 flags=N db=2 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20496 events=r cmd=ping user=default
id=271 addr=127.0.0.1:48844 fd=15 name= age=63 idle=14 flags=P db=2 sub=0 psub=1 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20504 events=r cmd=ping user=default
```

I have tried changing  `--concurrency=1`, as well as `CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT=None` and `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'max_connections': 1}` but none seems to change the number of connexions to redis.

My question is what is making all this connexions and what for exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what is making all this connexions and what for exactly ?

The connections are all created at once and are pooled and persistent among *all* the tasks you create. So it's normal for all the connections to start right away. Using a connection pool is more efficient because connections can be reused -- creating new connections has a lot of overhead, so creating connections in advance and keeping them around is beneficial.

Because the connections are *pooled*, changing `--concurrency` has no effect; if you add more concurrency, they still use the same connection pool with same number of connections.

Individual tasks (the greenlets) must use a redis connection to acknowledge tasks, for example, as part of the normal broker workflow.

Is there a reason why you need less than 10 connections (the default)?

If you are trying to limit the number of connections, you should NOT set `CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT=None`. This will likely cause more connections to be created when tasks actually run because setting this to `None` will cause a new connection will be made *every* time a connection to redis is needed then immediately closed. This adds a lot of overhead and in most cases is not a good idea.

Also, all celery settings must be prefixed with `CELERY_` when set in the django settings. So you should use `CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS` not `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I needed the number of connections to be low because I’m already using 12 connections on heroku with 20 max connexions offered by redis free plan. I understand I may need to upgrade, but how many connections should I plan for considering I also want to use a beat worker (for scheduled tasks) and flower for monitoring.